Al momento de implementar unas dependencias, aparece el error "El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso"
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de java web. El proyecto estaba funcionando bien pero al momento de implementar unas dependencias, cuando intento ejecutar mi proyecto, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2:war (default-war) on project PQRS: Failed to copy file for artifact [com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.3.0:compile]: C:\Users\Johan OrdoÃ±ez\Desktop\Universidad Mariana\Quinto semestre\Estructuras de datos ll\PQRS\PQRS\target\PQRS-1.0\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar: El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque estÃ¡ siendo utilizado por otro proceso -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Ya intenté de todo y nada, ¿podría ser la ubicación de las librerías?
